# Slow operation of PySide QFileSystemModel used by QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Im using a widget in a new app to provide a list of files in the current directory.  It works but startup operation is very slow and whenever moving up or down the directory tree the update and display of the new directory is also slow.

Below is the Class used for the file explorer part of the app;

```
class FileList(QFrame):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(FileList, self).__init__(parent)
    # self.setFrameStyle(self.WinPanel|self.Raised)
    lo50 = QVBoxLayout(self)
    lo50.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.setLayout(lo50)
    self.cwdtext = QLineEdit(self)
    self.cwdtext.setReadOnly(True)

    lo50.addWidget(self.cwdtext)

    self.list = QTableView(self)
    self.list.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.list.setShowGrid(False)
    self.list.setWordWrap(False)
    self.list.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
    vh = self.list.verticalHeader()
    vh.hide()
    vh.setDefaultSectionSize(20)

    self.filemodel = QFileSystemModel(self)
    self.filemodel.setFilter(QDir.AllDirs | QDir.Files | QDir.NoDot | QDir.Drives | QDir.AllEntries)
    self.filemodel.setNameFilterDisables(False)

    self.list.setModel(self.filemodel)

    lo50.addWidget(self.list)
    self.chdir(QDir.currentPath())
    self.list.doubleClicked.connect(self.doubleclick)

def chdir(self, directory):
    newdir = obj2str(directory)
    i = self.filemodel.setRootPath(newdir)
    self.list.setRootIndex(i)
    cwd = os.path.abspath(newdir)
    os.chdir(cwd)
    self.cwdtext.setText(cwd)
    return i

def doubleclick(self, index):
    if self.filemodel.isDir(index):
        self.chdir(self.filemodel.filePath(index))
    else:
        print(self.filemodel.filePath(index))
```

Comment: What platform are you on? Works fine for me on Linux. Folders with about 5000 entries load in less than a second, and the overall performance is somewhat better than a dedicated file-manager application (probably because of the icons).

Comment: Im on Windows 7.  It is strange as I cannot see any good reason for  the delays. I also am using directories with less than 100 files in.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is down to PySide and the QFileSystemModel itself.

Im using PySide version 1.2.1 with QtCore 4.8.6 and I found today it worked fine for an hour without any changes to this area of code and then reverted back again to slow operation.  I think I might look to create my own simpler model for the view or try PyQt4.

Comment: If there was a fundamental problem with QFileSystemModel on Windows, I would expect to find lots of people complaining about it. But although some searching does pick up a few relevant bug reports, there is nothing really definitive. This leads me to suspect that there is something unusual about your system setup that might be exposing a problem. Are you able to test on some other Windows machines? I tried with Win XP in a VM, and the `windows/system32` folder only took about a second or so to load.